# É seguro usar List com Parallel.ForEach?

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety

Estou fazendo um fazendo um método estilo *crawler* que recebe uma lista de string, faz uma chamada em um site, insere o retorno em outra lista e retorna.

Meu método está funcionando, mas está muito lento, então quero paralelizar as chamadas.
Pelo que pesquisei o `Parallel.ForEach` resolve facilmente esse problema, mas é seguro usar ele com `List`?

Meu código atual:

```
private List<Veiculo> ObtemTodosVeiculos(List<string> modelos)
{
    List<Veiculo> veiculos = new List<Veiculo>();
    foreach (var modelo in modelos)
    {
        string retorno = GET(string.Format("https://192.168.0.1/modelo/{0}", modelo));
        var veiculo = Deserializa<Veiculo>(retorno);
        if (veiculo != null)
            veiculos.Add(veiculo);
    }
    return veiculos;
}
```

Comment: melhor solução para o seu problema é tornar o seu método `GET` assincrono. Dessa forma você obteria uma lista de Task e poderia utilizar `Task.WaitAll` para esperar por todas "ao mesmo tempo". Mas tenha cuidado com isto. O seu método `GET` tem que usar métodos assicnronos também. Não é só chegar lá e escrever `async` que tudo vai funcionar maravilha... O melhor mesmo é usar [um cliente que suporta isso](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Meu método está funcionando, mas está muito lento, então quero paralelizar as chamadas. Pelo que pesquisei o `Parallel.ForEach` resolve facilmente esse problema, mas é seguro usar ele com `List`?

## Não

`List` e qualquer classe fora de `System.Collections.Concurrent` **não são *thread-safe***. [Prefira uma das coleções listadas aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd997305(v=vs.110).aspx).

Outra forma é [proteger a lista numa região crítica](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/c5kehkcz.aspx), mas isso trará outras penalidades de desempenho, porque `List` não é otimizada para concorrência.

```
private Object obj = new Object();
...

var veiculo = Deserializa<Veiculo>(retorno);
lock (obj) 
{
    if (veiculo != null)
        veiculos.Add(veiculo);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Depende. Se você consegue garantir que a lista não será modificada enquanto o `Parallel.ForEach` está sendo executado, então você não terá problema. Caso contrário, siga a sugestão do @CiganoMorrisonMendez.

Da [documentação de `List<T>` no MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx), seção de acesso thread-safe: "É seguro executar várias operações de leitura em um List, mas podem ocorrer problemas se a coleção é modificada enquanto está sendo lido".

Como Bruno Costa mencionou no comentário - no caso acima não há problema em usar a lista `modelos` de forma paralela. No entanto, a lista `veiculos` está sendo modificada em múltiplos threads, então o tipo dessa variável deve ser trocado para alguma das coleções que são thread-safe.

Comment: O caso dele envolve justamente uma modificação. Bem perigoso paralelizar o exemplo dele só com `List`.

Comment: Pelo trecho de código, a modificação é feita na lista `veiculos`, enquanto a paralelização seria feita na lista `modelos`. Se for somente esse o caso (i.e., não houver outras modificações que não são mostradas), então não deve ter problemas.

Comment: @carlosfigueira Sim, ele vai ter problemas. É verdade que o `Parallel.ForEach` vai percorrer todos os elementos de `modelos`, mas isso não implica que as escritas a `veiculo` não tenham problemas.

Comment: Meu objetivo é usar somente uma lista que vai ser instanciada fora do `Parallel.ForEach`, mas eu vou usar ela somente para adicionar itens, não vou usar como leitura, ainda assim tem problema?

Comment: @BrunoCosta, você tem razão - a paralelização na lista `modelos` é segura, mas a lista `veiculos` deve ser definida como uma lista thread-safe (do `System.Collections.Concurrent`).