# Qual é a melhor forma de fazer vários pedidos a uma API?

Tags: c#, http, paralelismo

Eu vim colocar esta pergunta mais uma vez achando que seria benéfico a comunidade ter uma forma canónica de fazer vários pedidos http a uma determinada API.

Mais concretamente [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/129316/%C3%89-seguro-usar-list-com-parallel-foreach#comment269405_129316) motivou-me a colocar a minha questão.

**Qual é a melhor forma de fazer vários pedidos a uma API? (Tenha em conta em reduzir ao máximo o tempo necessário para obter todas as respostas)**

Para ser um pouco mais concreto: Como posso obter as primeiras 10 páginas da api do stackechange, sendo https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?page=1&pagesize=10&order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow a primeira página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Utilizando Tasks**

A ideia é fazer os pedidos assincronamente e adicioná-los a uma lista de tasks com todos os pedidos. Depois espera-se pelas respsotas com `Task.WaitAll`:

```
var tasks = new Task<string>[10];
var api = "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers?page={0}&pagesize=10&site=stackoverflow";
using(var client = new HttpClient()){
    for(int i = 1 ; i < 11; ++i){
        var url = string.Format(api, i);
        tasks[i-1] = client.GetAsync(url)
            .ContinueWith(t => t.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
            .Unwrap();
    }

    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    foreach (var resposta in tasks){
        Console.WriteLine(resposta.Result);
    }
}
```

Na verdade [esta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/123707/melhores-pr%C3%A1ticas-ao-trabalhar-com-multithread/123716#123716) questiona esta mesma abordagem.

Uma alternativa (segundo uma medição rápida) mais eficiente do que a de cima e eventualmente mais compreensível pode ser obtida com a utilização da keyword `await`:

```
var tasks = new List<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>();
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    for (int i = 1; i < paginas; ++i)
    {
        var url = string.Format(api, i);
        tasks.Add(client.GetAsync(url));
    }

    var respostas = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    var todas = new List<string>();
    foreach(var resposta in respostas)
    {
        todas.Add(await resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
    return todas;
}
```

Mas **nunca** faça o seguinte código:

```
var respostas = new List<string>();
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    for (int i = 1; i < paginas; ++i)
    {
        var url = string.Format(api, i);
        var resposta = await client.GetAsync(url);
        respostas.Add(await resposta.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
    }
}
return respostas;
```

Com este código os pedidos não estão a ser feitos de forma paralela e demoram por isso mais tempo.

Comment: Bruno, aconselho que uso as palavras chave async/await

Comment: @TobyMosque `await` só seria necessário se eu optásse por usar `Task.WhenAll` em vez de `Task.WaitAll`. Se eu usar `await` dentro do for vou demorar 10x mais tempo a executar o código.

Comment: você pode tentar usar o `Parallel.For(0, 10, async i => { ... return await client...Unwrap() });`

Comment: @TobyMosque Tive a fazer uma experiência e parece que o .Net é mais esperto do que estáva à espera. Em vez de demorar 10x mais ele demora "apenas" <numero de cores> vezes. Eu vou postar uma alternativa em que obtive um tempo de computação ligeiramente menor e que utiliza o `await`.

Comment: a minha preocupação é caso a API demore a responder, seja por instabilidade na sua aplicação, na camada de Transporte ou na propria API. neste caso o `await` pode lhe ajudar à manter a escabilidade da sua aplicação ao evitar que recursos fiquem presos sem necessidade.

Comment: @TobyMosque Não sei se o estou a perceber. Esperar por todos os pedidos ao mesmo tempo é melhor do que esperar um por um, a não ser que haja preocupações com memória. Falhas de transporte, ou servidor menos responsivo podem ocorrer quer com 1 pedido quer com n pedidos e nada evita disso.

Comment: apenas apontei o motivo pelo qual eu mencionei o uso de async/await, em todo caso a sua segunda alternativa me parece muito boa.